# Transparent nav bar cant click anything on it

Tags: javascript, html, css

why I can't hover over nav bar and click anything? I want transparent nav bar with sliding more bars when i hover. any ideas? It looks like that my nav bar is behind background image and if i change it around background just starts to fall apart. I am just a beginner don't be angry. Also how can you make a space between nav bar if I wanted on top right side sign in icon or something familiar how should I do that?

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    color:#666;

}

.pimg1, .pimg2, .pimg3 {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0.7;
    background-position: center;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.pimg1 {
    background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/374870/pexels-photo-374870.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940");
    min-height: 100%;
}
.pimg2 {
    background-image: url("street.jpg");
    min-height: 400px;
}
.pimg3 {
    background-image: url("aus.jpg");
    min-height: 400px;
}

.section {
    text-align: center;
    padding:50px 80px;
}
.section-light {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    color:#666;
}
.section-light {
    background-color: #282e34;
    color:#ddd;
}
.ptext {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color:#000;
    font-size:27px;
    letter-spacing: 8px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.ptext .border {
    background-color: #111;
    color: #fff;
    padding:20px;
}
.ptext .border-trans {
    background-color: transparent;
}
@media(max-width: 568px) {
    .pimg1,.pimg2,.pimg3 {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style:none;
}
ul li {
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: .8;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:20px;
}

ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display:block;
}

ul li a:hover {
    background-color: blue;

}

ul li ul li {
    display:none;
}
ul li:hover ul li {
    display :block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Paralex website demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <nav>
            <ul>
                    
                <li><a href="index.html"><img class="icon" src="5.jpg"></a></li>
                <li><a>Components</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/videocards.html/">Video Cards</a></li>
                        <li><a>Displays</a></li>
                        <li><a>Cpu</a></li>
                        <li><a>Ram</a></li>
                        <li><a>Cooling System</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>Pre Built Computers</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>Laptop Computers</a></li>
                        <li><a>Desktop Computers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>Contacts</a></li>   
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="pimg1">
            <div class="ptext">
                <span class="border">
                    Beginners Website
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <section class="section section-light">
            <h2>Section one</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae suscipit harum nisi dolore nesciunt labore eaque aliquid ab obcaecati autem, repellendus hic id excepturi dolores earum aspernatur, corporis fuga maxime cumque unde omnis reiciendis soluta. Molestias iste consectetur excepturi quae illum veritatis, enim sit ipsa ipsum nesciunt harum perferendis cupiditate iusto doloribus atque veniam cum qui fugit ducimus alias officia. Repudiandae maiores est quod enim quas, quia omnis pariatur facere exercitationem, ullam ratione, perspiciatis corporis. Saepe enim dicta libero perspiciatis nesciunt, soluta unde. Atque recusandae magni veritatis odit id ducimus. Quam fugit illo quia quod amet assumenda, consectetur tempora ratione.
            </p>
    
    
        </section>

        <div class="pimg2">
                <div class="ptext">
                    <span class="border-trans">
                        Image 2 text
                    </span>
                </div>
        </div>

        <section class="section section-dark">
                <h2>Section one</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem, ipsum do obcaecati autem, repellendus hic id excepturi dolores earum aspernatur, corporis fuga maxime cumque unde omnis reiciendis soluta. Molestias iste consectetur excepturi quae illum veritatis, enim sit ipsa ipsum nesciunt harum perferendis cupiditate iusto doloribus atque veniam cum qui fugit ducimus alias officia. Repudiandae maiores est quod enim quas, quia omnis pariatur facere exercitationem, ullam ratione, perspiciatis corporis. Saepe enim dicta libero perspiciatis nesciunt, soluta unde. Atque recusandae magni veritatis odit id ducimus. Quam fugit illo quia quod amet assumenda, consectetur tempora ratione.
                </p>
           
           
            </section>
            <div class="pimg3">
                    <div class="ptext">
                        <span class="border-trans">
                            Image 3 text
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <section class="section section-light">
                    <h2>Section one</h2>
                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dde omnis reiciendis soluta. Molestias iste consectetur excepturi quae illum veritatis, enim sit ipsa ipsum nesciunt harum perferendis cupiditate iusto doloribus atque veniam cum qui fugit ducimus alias officia. Repudiandae maiores est quod enim quas, quia omnis pariatur facere exercitationem, ullam ratione, perspiciatis corporis. Saepe enim dicta libero perspiciatis nesciunt, soluta unde. Atque recusandae magni veritatis odit id ducimus. Quam fugit illo quia quod amet assumenda, consectetur tempora ratione.</p>
                   
                   
            </section>
                    <div class="pimg1">
                            <div class="ptext">
                                <span class="border">
                                    Beginners Website
                                </span>
                            </div>
                    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this style

```
nav {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Also change the background-color of li

```
ul li {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Your `pimg1` div is covering the nav element, because its relative. You need to set `positon: relative` on `nav` element also and give any value of `z-index` above 0. It should work.

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    color:#666;

}
nav {
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
} 
.pimg1, .pimg2, .pimg3 {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0.7;
    background-position: center;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.pimg1 {
    background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/374870/pexels-photo-374870.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940");
    min-height: 100%;
}
.pimg2 {
    background-image: url("street.jpg");
    min-height: 400px;
}
.pimg3 {
    background-image: url("aus.jpg");
    min-height: 400px;
}

.section {
    text-align: center;
    padding:50px 80px;
}
.section-light {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    color:#666;
}
.section-light {
    background-color: #282e34;
    color:#ddd;
}
.ptext {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color:#000;
    font-size:27px;
    letter-spacing: 8px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.ptext .border {
    background-color: #111;
    color: #fff;
    padding:20px;
}
.ptext .border-trans {
    background-color: transparent;
}
@media(max-width: 568px) {
    .pimg1,.pimg2,.pimg3 {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style:none;
}
ul li {
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: transparent;
    opacity: .8;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:20px;
}

ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display:block;
}

ul li a:hover {
    background-color: blue;

}

ul li ul li {
    display:none;
}
ul li:hover ul li {
    display :block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Paralex website demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <nav>
            <ul>
                    
                <li><a href="index.html"><img class="icon" src="5.jpg"></a></li>
                <li><a>Components</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/videocards.html/">Video Cards</a></li>
                        <li><a>Displays</a></li>
                        <li><a>Cpu</a></li>
                        <li><a>Ram</a></li>
                        <li><a>Cooling System</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>Pre Built Computers</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>Laptop Computers</a></li>
                        <li><a>Desktop Computers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>Contacts</a></li>   
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="pimg1">
            <div class="ptext">
                <span class="border">
                    Beginners Website
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <section class="section section-light">
            <h2>Section one</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae suscipit harum nisi dolore nesciunt labore eaque aliquid ab obcaecati autem, repellendus hic id excepturi dolores earum aspernatur, corporis fuga maxime cumque unde omnis reiciendis soluta. Molestias iste consectetur excepturi quae illum veritatis, enim sit ipsa ipsum nesciunt harum perferendis cupiditate iusto doloribus atque veniam cum qui fugit ducimus alias officia. Repudiandae maiores est quod enim quas, quia omnis pariatur facere exercitationem, ullam ratione, perspiciatis corporis. Saepe enim dicta libero perspiciatis nesciunt, soluta unde. Atque recusandae magni veritatis odit id ducimus. Quam fugit illo quia quod amet assumenda, consectetur tempora ratione.
            </p>
    
    
        </section>

        <div class="pimg2">
                <div class="ptext">
                    <span class="border-trans">
                        Image 2 text
                    </span>
                </div>
        </div>

        <section class="section section-dark">
                <h2>Section one</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem, ipsum do obcaecati autem, repellendus hic id excepturi dolores earum aspernatur, corporis fuga maxime cumque unde omnis reiciendis soluta. Molestias iste consectetur excepturi quae illum veritatis, enim sit ipsa ipsum nesciunt harum perferendis cupiditate iusto doloribus atque veniam cum qui fugit ducimus alias officia. Repudiandae maiores est quod enim quas, quia omnis pariatur facere exercitationem, ullam ratione, perspiciatis corporis. Saepe enim dicta libero perspiciatis nesciunt, soluta unde. Atque recusandae magni veritatis odit id ducimus. Quam fugit illo quia quod amet assumenda, consectetur tempora ratione.
                </p>
           
           
            </section>
            <div class="pimg3">
                    <div class="ptext">
                        <span class="border-trans">
                            Image 3 text
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <section class="section section-light">
                    <h2>Section one</h2>
                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dde omnis reiciendis soluta. Molestias iste consectetur excepturi quae illum veritatis, enim sit ipsa ipsum nesciunt harum perferendis cupiditate iusto doloribus atque veniam cum qui fugit ducimus alias officia. Repudiandae maiores est quod enim quas, quia omnis pariatur facere exercitationem, ullam ratione, perspiciatis corporis. Saepe enim dicta libero perspiciatis nesciunt, soluta unde. Atque recusandae magni veritatis odit id ducimus. Quam fugit illo quia quod amet assumenda, consectetur tempora ratione.</p>
                   
                   
            </section>
                    <div class="pimg1">
                            <div class="ptext">
                                <span class="border">
                                    Beginners Website
                                </span>
                            </div>
                    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```